# Execute a Task of a sub-module of a Gradle multiproject

Tags: gradle, multi-project, gradle-task

I have the following multiproject structure:

**settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'toolbox-backend'
include 'toolbox-components-rest'
include 'toolbox-components-executor'
include 'toolbox-components-toolsyncer'
```

I'd love to create a task in my root *build.gradle* which will call the **clean**, **build**, **install** (application) and finally the **run** task of the **toolbox-components-rest** submodule.

Answer (score 1):

```
task startREST() {

dependsOn ':toolbox-components-rest:clean'
dependsOn ':toolbox-components-rest:build'
dependsOn ':toolbox-components-rest:bootRun'

println "[Toolbox $version] Starting REST interface..."
}
```

This does work - BUT the bootRun task is running before build which runs before clean. I'd like to have it exactly the other way around

Fixed the above with

```
bootRun.mustRunAfter build
build.mustRunAfter clean
```

in the gradle.build of the **toolbox-components-rest** submodule